# Enable Bluetooth communication with iRobot Create 2

Tags: irobot-create

I just got a new iRobot Create 2. I used to use an Element Direct BAM (Bluetooth Adapter Module) for iRobot Create previously.

How can I communicate with a Create 2 using Bluetooth? What accessories do I need?

Answer (score 1):

The Create 2 [projects page](http://www.irobot.com/About-iRobot/STEM/Create-2/Projects.aspx) has a tutorial on how to make a [Bluetooth serial module](http://www.irobotweb.com/~/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/Bluetooth_Serial.pdf?la=en).

The [Rootooth](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/12581) should work too.  Although it is no longer sold, but you might be able to find one somewhere.  Or make one yourself since SparkFun put all the designs online.

I couldn't find much information on the BAM, but I bet you could make it work with the Create2.  Consult the above mentioned projects page to determine the new Create pinout and if any level shifting is required.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I will try to make one using the instructions provided in Bluetooth serial module.